# Reduce button height in GTK+

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I am creating a GTK+ 3 C application that has a very long list. The application needs to register when the user clicks on any of the list items. Right now I'm making the list out of GTK+ buttons because the styling is the clearest way to communicate the functionality. However the generous vertical padding means the buttons take up about twice as much space as they need to.

How would I go about reducing the height of the buttons?

The image below shows what I mean by padding and height. I would like the text to take up the majority of the vertical space, rather than the padding. This means the height needs to be reduced.
[image]

The following is the code I use to create a button. `loglist` is a box element oriented vertically.

```
    GtkWidget* btn = gtk_button_new();
    GtkWidget* box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    GtkWidget* text = gtk_label_new("Data");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), text, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(btn), box);
    gtk_widget_set_halign(text, GTK_ALIGN_START);
    gtk_button_set_relief(GTK_BUTTON(btn), GTK_RELIEF_NONE);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(loglist), btn, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
```

Comment: if your styling a gtk button {bacnground-image: none } should be set..  for easy styling you can try gtk inspector (https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GTK/Inspector?action=show&redirect=Projects%2FGTK%2B%2FInspector)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to reduce. You mention "button height" in title and "padding" in the body of your question. Maybe you could add some image what you want to remove. And you might also add the code how you create the buttons and the container where you add the buttons.

Comment: @Medynsky It is unclear what are you trying to achieve. [Maybe a GTK course Helps?](http://YouTube.com/MichaelB-GTK)

Comment: If I understand right, you need a Button which has its heigh to be same size as the visible label has. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: I am going to check this issue tomorrow if you do not get an answer until then. Play with margins and padding from the button and its label in the CSS file.

Comment: I don't have a CSS file, which may be my problem, but I have brought up the app in the inspector and can alter with the css there. Preferably I would set the styling in the code. If I were to add a css file would the program still be a single contained executable or would a css file need to be chained to it wherever it went?

Comment: if you add it as a css file then you have to ship the file along with your application. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider. I think the following ways are possible 1) you can add the css as a string in the code and load it as a resource or 2) like you can do individual styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution I worked out using the information everyone provided me.

```
GtkCssProvider* css = gtk_css_provider_new();
GdkScreen* screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen(gdk_display_get_default());
GtkStyleContext* context;

gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(css),
        GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(css,
        "button {padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: -8px;}",
        -1, NULL);

/* Insert Buttons */
context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(btn);
gtk_style_context_add_class(context, "data_btn");
/* End Insert Buttons */

g_object_unref(css);
```

The result can be seen below.

[image]

The code between the "Insert Buttons" comments need to be included with the rest of the code for inserting buttons, after the btn widget has been declared and assigned. The code I use to insert buttons can be seen in the question. I insert those two lines after the GtkWidget declarations but before anything else. I could get the same effect using the "button" tag rather than the ".data_btn" tag, but then it would affect all buttons not just the list.

A negative margin is generally bad practice because it can and will break if themes are changed, and it needs an extra box of padding underneath all the buttons. For me it's a placeholder until I can figure something else out, it will go away in the future.

I wanted everything to be in a single executable. If you, the person who found this through google or whatever, don't have that same goal then you would be better off using a css file. Use the [gtk_css_provider_load_from_file](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html#gtk-css-provider-load-from-file) function instead of the [load_from_data](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html#gtk-css-provider-load-from-data) function.